# codeigniter , phpmailer attached file download as untitled

Tags: codeigniter, phpmailer, email-attachments

I am using phpmailer with Codeigniter to send an email with pdf attachment . 
Email is sending successfully , but when pdf is download from the email, it is save as untitled. 
any Idea about this ? why it is happening

```
$pdf->Output(FCPATH . 'uploads/orderReport.pdf', 'F');
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$subject = 'Order Reports for ' . date('d-m-Y', $start_date) . ' to'.
date('d-m-Y', $end_date);
$message = '<p>Hello Dear,</p>';
$message .= '<p>Please find Order report form ' . date('d-m-Y', $start_date) . ' to ' . date('d-m-Y', $end_date) . '</p>';
$message .= '<p>Regards</p>';
$this->email->attach(FCPATH . 'uploads/orderReport.pdf', '', '',       'application/pdf');
$this->email->from('no-replay@laviviane.com')
            ->to($email_address)
            ->subject($subject)
            ->message($message)
            ->send();
```

Comment: Edit question and place the part of code where you are giving name to the attachment file.

Comment: Code is added please check now if you any idea about this

Comment: It's because you left third parameter of `attach` method blank. Try it like in example from [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/email.html#CI_Email::attach).